How can I pass parameter to @Composable parameter from @Composable where first one is nested?
I want to make navigation with Scaffold and because of using this Scaffold in each screen, I want not to boilerplate.
I have three fun. ParentComposable is 'most parent' wrapper @Composable, there is TestScaffold, where I need to pass every @Composable content, so in this case I want to pass CustomColumn as contentComponent parameter. But Scaffold TopAppBar intersects with contentComponent, so I need to pass padding.calculateTopPadding() upside to TestScaffold and then pass it to CustomColumn inside.
How can i do it?
It's more common question, not based just with TopAppBar, but every @Composable
@Composable
fun ParentComposable() {
    Row {
        TestScaffold(
            contentComponent = CustomColumn(?here I want pass modifier with padding from scaffold?)
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun CustomColumn(modifier: Modifier) {
    Column(modifier = modifier) {
        Spacer(modifier = modifier)
        Text("Foo")
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun TestScaffold(contentComponent: @Composable (modifierForContent: Modifier) -> Unit = {}) {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = { Text(text = "Game App", textAlign = TextAlign.Center) },
                navigationIcon = {}
            )
        },
        content = { padding ->
            contentComponent(
                modifierForContent = Modifier.padding(padding)
            )
        }
    )
}


If you only need the Modifier to pass the padding, you could consider to just use one additional Composable in your TestScaffold and apply the padding there:
@Composable
fun TestScaffold(contentComponent: @Composable () -> Unit = {}) {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            // ...
        },
        content = { padding ->
            Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(padding)) {
                contentComponent()
            }
        }
    )
}


Since TestScaffold expects a function accepting a modifier, we should provide a function accepting a modifier on caller side like :
@Composable
fun ParentComposable() {
    Row {
        TestScaffold(
            contentComponent = { modifier -> CustomColumn(modifier) }
        )
    }
}

